# Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' in SPFX web part

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I have spfx web part version 1.8.2 which is working in chrome but not in ie11.
At first the I had **Object doesn't support property or method 'find'** error then I added the below packages

```
import 'polyfill-array-includes';
import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "es6-map/implement";
import "core-js/modules/es6.array.find";
```

Then the new error is throwing as **Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'**

Any thoughts? Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://www.cluemediator.com/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-includes-in-ie

just put this in constructor for example:

```js
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function (searchElement, fromIndex) {
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      function sameValueZero(x, y) {
        return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
      }

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
          return true;
        }
        // c. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    },
  });
}
```